# Check for ALL permission (Doc lib, lists, etc) of a specific user in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way where can I search all permission of a certain user in Sharepoint? Because right now, the way I know is to navigate individually through ALL doc lib to check if that user has a permission on it. (Or belongs to a group that has permission on it). 
My colleague ask me to give permission to a certain person and should be the same with her current permissions. So what I did is from the site, I navigate `Site Actions > Site Permissions > Check Permissions`. From there I take note of the groups that my colleague belongs to and add the new user into it. But the user cannot access that particular Doc lib he needed. Is there a way where I can see ALL possible permissions of a certain user so that I don't need to check ALL doc lib or lists individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign permissions directly to the user is a bad pattern, better assign permissions to a group and assign the user to the group.

To check user permissions for the whole site you must use a powershell script, below a script taken from another post from [stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/powershell-script-to-find-permissions-for-a-specific-user)

```
$urlWeb = "http://sp2010"
Get-SPUser -Web $urlWeb | select UserLogin, @{name=”Exlicit given roles”;expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name=”Roles given via groups”;expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | format-Table -auto
```